# charCodeAt() - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need some advice to use charCodeAt() method.

My codes are below:

```
doParity() {
var str = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"];
var arr = str[0][0] + str[1][0] + str[2][0];    // arr = "aei"

var bin = [];
var par = [];
var parity;
var result = [];
 // line 8
 for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
   bin[j] = this.toBin(str[j][0]);      // bin[j] is 8bit binary number
   par[j] = bin[j][0];                  // when j=0, str[j][0] = 'a',
                                        //           bin[j] = 01100001,
                                        //           par[j] = 0 
   if (j == 0) parity = par[j] ^ par[j + 1];
   else parity ^= parity[j + 1];
   alert(parity);
 }
//line 18
//for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
//  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
//    bin[j] = this.toBin(str[j][i]);
//    par[j] = bin[j][i];
//    if (j == 0) parity = par[j] ^ par[j + 1];
//    else parity ^= parity[j + 1];
//  }
//  result[i] = parity;
//}
//alert(result);
}

toBin(str) {           // This function get ASCII value and return 8bit binary number of it. 
  var st, i, j, d;
  var arr = [];
  var len = str.length;
  for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
  //reverse so its like a stack
    d = str.charCodeAt(len - i);
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      arr.push(d % 2);
      d = Math.floor(d / 2);
    }
  }
  //reverse all bits again.
  return arr.reverse().join("");
}
```

The Line8's for loop works well, then I coded the Line18's loop because I need to get 8bit xor variables, however it doesn't work.

It gives me [image: this error].

This code is very simple, but I'm still wandering.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `str[j][0]` returns `undefined` because `str` is not a 2d array.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the comments; it bypasses Stack Overflow's quality controls, and you deprive yourself of the sweet sweet answer points.

Comment: @AdamBarnes  I agree with your assessment, but I might be able to give insight into why this happens.  Often answers get down-voted, for no apparent reason.  This is a major flaw in SO atm., and looks like something the DEV's are unlikely to fix.  Simple fix would be all down-votes need a reason.  Or alternatively down-votes removed totally, if answer is useful, up-votes would be enough to push the best to top.

Comment: I disagree with you entirely.  Downvotes are very important to the ecosystem of the site, and are one of the _main_ quality controls I was referring to.  This isn't something the site owners need to "fix", because it's entirely intended behaviour.  Downvotes are rarely given for no reason, only sometimes without explanation.  If you receive one, look honestly at your answer and ask yourself if you could have done better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is your problem

`str[j][0]` returns `undefined` because `str` is not a 2d array

Remove the second access `[0]` from your arrays.

## Look at this code snippet with those fixes

```js
function doParity() {
  var str = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"];
  var arr = str[0] + str[1] + str[2]; // arr = "aei"

  var bin = [];
  var par = [];
  var parity;
  var result = [];
  // line 8
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    bin[j] = this.toBin(str[j]); // bin[j] is 8bit binary number
    par[j] = bin[j]; // when j=0, str[j][0] = 'a',
    //           bin[j] = 01100001,
    //           par[j] = 0 
    if (j == 0) parity = par[j] ^ par[j + 1];
    else parity ^= parity[j + 1];
    alert(parity);
  }
  //line 18
  //for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  //  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  //    bin[j] = this.toBin(str[j][i]);
  //    par[j] = bin[j][i];
  //    if (j == 0) parity = par[j] ^ par[j + 1];
  //    else parity ^= parity[j + 1];
  //  }
  //  result[i] = parity;
  //}
  //alert(result);
}

function toBin(str) { // This function get ASCII value and return 8bit binary number of it. 
  var st, i, j, d;
  var arr = [];
  var len = str.length;
  for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    //reverse so its like a stack
    d = str.charCodeAt(len - i);
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      arr.push(d % 2);
      d = Math.floor(d / 2);
    }
  }
  //reverse all bits again.
  return arr.reverse().join("");
}

doParity();
```

Comment: Thanks. I just thought that's the way to create 2d array in JavaScript because I can access the variables like this: `str[0][0]`.

Comment: @qumm Javascript is  weakly typed, so allows those kind of stuff :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    bin[j] = this.toBin(str[j][i]);
```

From your loop `j` goes up to `7` but all the strings in `str` are 4 characters long. `str[0][7]` is undefined.

```js
var str = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"];
console.log(str[0][0]);
console.log(str[0][7]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer about str[j][0] being wrong as str is not a 2d array is semi-wrong. Although it is a 1d array of strings, if you do [index] on a string you will get the char at that index, so str[j][0] does not return undefined and so you can do a .length on it (although it will always be 1): it returns the first char of the j'th string. I ran the code you wrote and it works "fine" for me: I get 3 alerts with '0' as the message. So although your method logic is flawed, the code should run without errors.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The code is working if you didn't delete annotation. I want to make things working as I want in the Line18's loop.